# Need only one Tab in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++

I have no use for multitap functionality in NotePad++. But I keep ending up keep closing old Tabs which is a waste of time (in my case).

Is there any way to make NotePad++ only show 1 Tab which is current document?

Again, I have no need to see historical documents I opened.

Comment: According to the internet, this should be under `Settings -> Preferences -> Multi-Instance` and select the option to always use multiple instances.

Comment: @Toto , True but I don't  want to see any other open tabs other than the file I open.

Comment: @Toto So you say if you open 2 files one after another, you only see 1 file in 1 tab?? I don't see this behavior. In my case 2 tabs created.

Comment: Yes, you're right I'm wrong, sorry ;(. There is a way to close all open documents except the active one: Menu File >> Close More >> Close All But Active Document. This allows to close all but one documents in a single click. It doesn't exactly answer your question but it's quicker than close all documents 1 at a time.